# Is Stack Exchange contributing back to ProseMirror?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, open-source, stacks-editor

Stack Exchange has released [an alpha version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) of a new WYSIWYG editor based on the open source project [ProseMirror](https://prosemirror.net/).

In addition to benefitting from this open source work, is SE giving back to it and helping the FOSS ecosystem? In particular:

- Did SE just fork the editor, or are they contributing back to the main project the new features they add for their internal use? From [the contributor](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/graphs/contributors) [graphs](https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror/graphs/contributors) of the two projects, it seems that the answer is no, at least for now (still true as of July 2022). And I don't see any pull requests. Is this planned for the future?
- Are they supporting ProseMirror's author? It is his explicit request on the project's page that business users do it:

> If you are using ProseMirror to make profit, there is a **social** expectation that you help fund its maintenance.   [Start here](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/fund/).

(I am not affiliated in any way to ProseMirror, and I had never heard of the project before SE announced their editor.)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, our new editor doesn't currently support MathJax and isn't (as of yet) using Prosemirror. We're certainly discussing the concerns about how to support our sites that use MathJax but we haven't as of yet chosen a path forward in regards to the issue. While Prosemirror is *an* option, there are concerns about it, such as the fact it uses KaTeX instead of LaTeX. As such, this question is somewhat premature.

Comment: @Catija Maybe we interpret the imports wrong then shown here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/blob/main/src/external-plugins/stack-snippets.ts and here https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/tree/main/src/shared/prosemirror-plugins as it looks like bits from Prosemirror are used.

Comment: We're using Prosemirror as the backing for our new editor. The MathJax support is a separate (although related) issue - that's where [prosemirror-math](https://github.com/benrbray/prosemirror-math) comes in. We've talked a bit about looking into KaTeX, but I believe the current intent is still to see how we can support MathJax better first. In terms of contributing back, I don't *think* we created anything for our editor yet that'd be more broadly reusable or found any bugs that would be useful to upstream, but I'm not super familiar with the implementation details.

Comment: @AdamLear I think thats a very narrow-minded way to look at contributing back. The easiest would ofcourse be funding the project, but if that's not how you would like to operate, as it is open-source after all, you could always contribute in "time", there are plenty of open [issues](https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror/issues)

Comment: Related: [Is Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow still donating to open-source projects as part of Stack Gives Back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362493/335251) – and now also: [Stack Gives Back to Open Source 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383963/335251)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Exchange has [now provided some financial support to ProseMirror](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383963/579398) as a part of Stack Gives Back to Open Source 2022:

> - **[ProseMirror](https://prosemirror.net/)** ($2,000) - The foundation of the [Stacks Editor](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor).

Answer (score 22):

We don't have any plans for contributing code back to the main ProseMirror repo, though there have been issues fixed in ProseMirror related to issues that have arisen on our sites (and if we have the opportunity to contribute directly upstream, we will try to do so).

As far as financial support for the project, [we are planning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380688/51) on renewing financial support for open source projects this year, and while the actual donations are still to be made (and amounts determined), I can confirm that ProseMirror is at the top of our list for recipients. (Update: see [Stack Gives Back to Open Source 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383963/51) for more info: We gave ProseMirror $2,000).